# The method 'sendEmailVerification' isn't defined for the type 'UserCredential'. Firebase flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am following [this blog post](https://medium.com/@levimatheri/flutter-email-verification-and-password-reset-db2eed893d1d) to send email verification to users after they signup and this is the problem I'm getting when executing `sendEmailVerification()`

> The method 'sendEmailVerification' isn't defined for the type 'UserCredential'.
> Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'sendEmailVerification

But the problem with the blog post is that somethings that were used are deprecated and I managed to solve most of them except this one.

Here is my code:- (You can see the import statements for the name of packages)

```dart
    import 'dart:async';
    
    import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as auth;
    import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
    
    class Auth {
      final auth.FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = auth.FirebaseAuth.instance;
    
      Future<String> signUp(String email, String password) async {
        try {
          final user = await _firebaseAuth
              .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
          try {
            await user.sendEmailVerification(); // <== The error happens here
            return user;
          } catch (e) {
            print('Code was not sent!');
          }
        } catch (e) {
          print('An error occurred');
        }
      }
    }
```

Can you help me solve the issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
await user.user.sendEmailVerification();
```

Since `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` returns an instance of `UserCredential` and since the class [`UserCredential`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/user_credential.dart#L9) has a property called `user` which returns an instance of `User`.

Therefore you can use the property `user` to call the method [`sendEmailVerification()`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/firebase_auth/firebase_auth/lib/src/user.dart#L272) which is inside the class `User`.

Comment: Hi Peter, I would maybe indicate that `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` returns a `UserCredential`: https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/createUserWithEmailAndPassword.html

Comment: sure added Renaud

Answer (score 1):

[createUserEmailAndPassword()](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/createUserWithEmailAndPassword.html) returns a `Future<UserCredential>`, and a [UserCredential](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential-class.html) object has no method called `sendEmailVerification`.  That's what the error message is complaining about.

If you have a UserCredential to work with, then you can request email verification like this using its [user](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/UserCredential/user.html) property like this:

```
try {
    final credential = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
    await credential.user.sendEmailVerification();
    return credential.user;
} catch (e) {
    print('Code was not sent!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to be aware of I couldn't get this to work until I tried using a different email address. Somehow my first email address got glitched out by firebase.